# MPI - logic circle of processes

Tags: c, mpi

I am building a simple application that builds a logic circle in three iterations and then prints the result. First of all, I am using blocking Send and Recv, from process 0, I am using Send and Recv, up to final n-1 process, which sends to process 0. In process 0 I have this code in main:

```
int i;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD;&myrank);



if(myrank==0){


    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      MPI_Send(msg,MPI_CHAR,myrank+1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Recv(msg,100,MPI_CHAR, numtasks-1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
      printf("hello");
    }
  }
  else if(myrank==(numtasks-1)){
     MPI_Recv(msg,100,MPI_CHAR,numtasks-2,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
     MPI_Send(msg,100,MPI_CHAR,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  }
  else{
     MPI_Recv(msg,100,MPI_CHAR,myrank-1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
     MPI_Send(msg,100,MPI_CHAR,myrank+1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
```

I am trying now to get 3 results, I am right? But still I am getting only one. Rest of code is simple, for processes other then 0, they recieve from myrank-1 (myrank is number of actual process) and send to rank+1... Still I don't get it... Thanks for you ideas.

Answer (score 3):

`MPI_Send` may choose to wait for the receiving side to call `MPI_Recv`. So if all your processes start out by calling `MPI_Send`, all of them will hang. Try using `MPI_Isend` instead, and then check that each message has been received with `MPI_Waitall`.

EDIT: I have no idea how I managed to overlook the fact that there is a loop in the first `if` block... *embarrassed*. I guess I focussed too much on the MPI part. Try running the code *without* the loop (but with the loop body still present); then it should work as expected (with, say, n = 3 processes):

1. 0 sends to 1 and waits to receive from 2
2. 1 receives from 0, sends to 2, and exits
3. 2 receives from 1, sends to 0, and exits
4. 0 receives from 2, prints message, and exits

Now, reinsert the loop again. The exact same thing will happen, except that process 0 will continue after step 4 and will send to process 1, *which has exited*. Try to insert loops into the `else if` and `else` blocks too, or remove the loop from the `if` block and wrap the entire `if / else if / else` in a loop.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. (I amended your response for how to block.)

Comment: @chrisaycock: Ah; `MPI_Waitall` seems familiar. :-) +1.

Comment: Just first process starts with MPI_Send, others stars with MPI_Recv and then continue with MPI_Send. And its weird to me, that it will do only once and then nothing, even if it shouhld go 3 times...

Comment: @Hmyzak: Strange; then it should work. Can you post the code for the other processes?

Comment: @Hmyzak: Strange; it looks correct to me (although it's been a while since I coded MPI). But do you have any other code below what you've shown? You have no `printf` in the `else if` and `else` branches, so if this is all of the code, then nothing will be printed in the other processes, even if they receive the messages...

Comment: No, code is so simple and I think there should by written 3 times Hello on the screen... and it's not

Comment: @Hmyzak: I have no idea how I managed to overlook the fact that there is a loop in the first `if` block... :-( I'll edit my post with an explanation.